# GTM Enhanced Ecommerce Purchase Event

Tags: google-analytics, configuration, google-tag-manager

I am implementing the purchase tracking according to the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases).
I have a small problem with the purchase tag configuration.
If i create a tag with the provided configuration:

```
Tag type : Universal Analytics
Track type : Pageview
Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true
Use Data Layer: true
Trigger: event equals gtm.dom
```

it triggers on every page, which i don't want as it doubles my page views.
(page views are usually tracked via a AllPages-Pageview trigger).

I could add an event property to the object pushed to the dataLayer as it is done for the other ecommerce events (addToCart etc.) and an according trigger.

But as the documentation suggests a different way i assumed there is a reason and way to get the correct behavior using the provided documentation.

What am i missing and what is the correct trigger configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you are adding Enhanced Ecommerce on website you can have 1 page view tag with "enhanced ecommerce" feature turned on `(dataLayer = true)` and that will handle your page views as well as Enhanced Ecommerce data. However if you want page views to be tracked as we do in usual way you can send Enhanced Ecommerce data in "Events".

So for example for EE impressions you can create an event;

```
Event Category = Enhanced Ecommerce
Event Action = Product Impressions
Event Label = {{Page Path}}
And enable Enhanced Ecommerce feature on -> dataLayer = True
```

And add trigger for this event.

Similarly for Purchase EE you can create another event

```
Event Category = Enhanced Ecommerce
Event Action = Purchase
Event Label = {{Page Path}}
And enable Enhanced Ecommerce feature on -> dataLayer = True 

Add trigger = 
Trigger Type = Dom
Page Path = /checkout/success (or what ever your final confirmation page is)
```

If your EE purchase dataLayer contains an event you can create event trigger as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, short follow up question. Are there advantages using a Dom-Trigger over a CustomEvent-Trigger?

Comment: No if you already have an event available on dataLayer, I recommend you use that, if not available than use the DOM one.